# Use variable as SESSION Key

Tags: php

I am trying to save a session as either 1 or 0 and setup its key via another variable. Although when I go to use the SESSION data, it is not there. I am using the below code and would appreciate any advice.

```
session_start();
$num ='1';
            $_SESSION[$num] =='0';          
            if(isset($_SESSION[$num])){
                echo 'ran';
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is comparison, not assignment:

```
$_SESSION[$num] =='0';
```

Use a single equals sign:

```
$_SESSION[$num] = '0';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 $_SESSION[$num] =='0';
```

this should be

```
 $_SESSION[$num] ='0';
```

`=` is used for assignment and `==` used for comparison

Answer (score 0):

Only use one equal sign = not two ==

$_SESSION[$num] = '0';